# Database optimization/normalization - foreign key appearing in "too many" tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, normalization, telephony

I have done quite a lot of research and I believe that my database is in the 4th NF (was told that there is no need to go any further) but something still feels wrong.

I have a table TRUNK to which two tables refer via a foreign key: RATECARD as one trunk can be used in many ratecards (the differentiation being times when valid, callplans etc); furthermore I have a RATEBUYINGINFO which is basically info that you download from the trunk providers and contains info on rates to different destinations and similar. Obviously more RATEBUYINGINFO objects can be associated with one trunk as the price change over time, but the RATEBUYINGINFO and RATECARD are in no direct connection except that they may refer to a single trunk, so I have TrunkID as foreign key in both these tables.

Then I have the info with the selling rates (RATESELLINGINFO table) based on certain RATECARD and also destination info together with the trunk info all of which is kept track of in the RATEBUYINGINFO table (and no, I don't see the point in singling out DESTINATION as a separate table as different trunks by different providers do not provide unique destination names) so I have foreign keys RateCardID and RateBuyingInfoID as foreign keys in RATESELLINGINFO table.

Now the problem is that via these two foreign key the last table has access to two TrunkID values (one in RATECARD and one in RATEBUYINGINFO) which should always be the same (obviously one selling rate refers to a single trunk) but the database architecture won't guarantee that in any way.
Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask questions like this, always include SQL CREATE TABLE statements and some sample data as SQL INSERT statements. SQL is much more reliable and less ambiguous than your comments. (You can edit your question and add that stuff now to get better answers from people who read this later.)

The trunk id in both the tables RATECARD and RATEBUYINGINFO should probably be part of the primary key or part of a unique constraint in both those tables. If it is, then you can store trunk id once in RATESELLINGINFO with overlapping foreign key constraints.  Something like

```
...
foreign key (trunk_id, rate_card_id) 
  references ratecard (trunk_id, rate_card_id),
foreign key (trunk_id, rate_buying_info_id)
  references rate_buying_info (trunk_id, rate_buying_info_id)
...
```

Trunk id would have ended up in RATESELLINGINFO anyway (probably) if you'd done a full relational model.

Additional tip: drop the word "info" from your table names. All tables contain info; adding that to the name is just noise.